# QGIS: rotatable markers with offset from point

Tags: qgis, python, labeling, markers

Im wondering, if its possible (in QGIS), to set a rotatable marker with offset from point, like in my example below. Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the rotation options coupled with the labels (e.g. background and placement under Labels) in the layer properties?